# Postgres Regex, everything after semicolon

Tags: postgresql

I need a regex pattern to get everything after semicolon in postgres.

I have a string '1234;4567' and I need a result: '4567'.
I know I need a substring(string from regex), but I have a problem with creating such regex.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a regex for that:

```
select substr('1234;4567', strpos('1234;4567', ';') + 1)
```

if there is never more than one `;` in the string, you can use `split_part()`:

```
select split_part('1234;4567', ';', 2)
```